# Scripting on Roblox - my button is not working

Tags: lua, roblox

```
v.ButtonPart.Touched:Connect(function(Hit)
        if Hit:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
            local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Hit.Parent)
            if Values.OwnerValue.Value == player then
                if v.ButtonPart.CanCollide == true and v.ButtonPart.Transparency == 0 then
                    if player:WaitForChild("leaderstats").Cash.Value >= v.Price.Value then
                        player.leaderstats.Cash.Value -= v.Price.Value
                        items[v.items.Value].Parent = Boughtitems
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end)
```

my button is not working.

Comment: Could you describe what's happening and what you want to happen? We can't really tell what's wrong otherwise.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason why this isn't working is because of the line:  `Hit:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")`. When you use `.Touched:Connect(function())`, the first argument of the function is whatever touched it, so if you walked over it, it would return "LeftLeg" or something along those lines. What you're trying to do is find "Humanoid" in whatever part touched it, which definitely won't work. Try replacing `if Hit:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then` with `if Hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then`.